# I have parsed the JSON Data in a Gridview and now I want to make it available offline

Tags: android, json

Is there a way to save the JSON data at the phone so that you can see the data if your phone is offline?

And what would be the best option to cache data ? SharedPreferences or SQLite database

Here is my code, which i am using to Parse JSON:

```
   if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(getApplicationContext())) 
        new GetDataTask().execute();



        class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            private static final String KEY_ICONURL ="http://droid.hol.es/images/"; ;
            ProgressDialog dialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                dialog = new ProgressDialog(Exit_View_Activity.this);

                dialog.show();
            }

            @Nullable
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                 jsonObject = JSONParser.getDataFromWeb();

                try {

                    if (jsonObject != null) {

                        if(jsonObject.length() > 0) {

                            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Keys.KEY_INFO);

                            int lenArray = array.length();
                            if(lenArray > 0) {
                                for(int jIndex = 0; jIndex < lenArray; jIndex++) {                                     
                                    MyDataModel model = new MyDataModel();


                                    JSONObject innerObject = array.getJSONObject(jIndex);
                                    String name = innerObject.getString(Keys.KEY_NAME);
                                    String viewtype = innerObject.getString(Keys.KEY_VIEWTYPE);
                                    String image = innerObject.getString(Keys.KEY_ICON);

                                    String Constantfilter = cat_id.replaceAll("[^0-9,]","");
                                    Log.i("CONSTANT :",Constantfilter);

                                   String[] numbers = Constantfilter.split(",");
                                    for (int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++) {
                                        Log.i("Number: ", numbers[i]);

                                      if(numbers[i].equals(Keys.CONSTANT_CAT)) {
                                            if (innerObject.getString(Keys.KEY_VIEWTYPE).equals("exit") || innerObject.getString(Keys.KEY_VIEWTYPE).equals("grid,exit")) {
                                                model.setName(name);
                                                model.setView_type(viewtype);
                                                model.setId(id);
                                                model.setImage(KEY_ICONURL + image);
                                                model.setCat_id(cat_id);
                                                model.setGrid_order_id(grid_order_id);
                                                list.add(model);
                                            }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                dialog.dismiss();

            if (list.size() > 0) {
                try {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    dataPath = objectToFile(list);

                    editor.putString("key_name5",dataPath);  // Saving string

                    // Save the changes in SharedPreferences
                    editor.commit(); // commit changes

                   // pref.getString("key_name5", null);
                    //   list = (ArrayList<MyDataModel>)objectFromFile(dataPath);
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.parentLayout),  pref.getString("key_name5", null), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: save the json in shared prefrnces and use it again

Comment: `SharedPreferences` if your data is small, `SQLite` if your data is large.

Comment: how ?  plz give in any example SharedPreferences i used but not working proparly

Comment: use sqlite database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You can create a class with any name for example I have created "LocalSharedPrefrences"

```
 public class LocalSharedPrefrences {
    private static final String strSharedPrefName = "AppPrefrence";
    private static final String homePageJosn = "homePageJosn";
public static void saveHomePageJosnData(Context context, String JsonData) {
        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(strSharedPrefName, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString(homePageJosn, JsonData);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getHomePageJosnData(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(strSharedPrefName, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String JsonData = pref.getString(homePageJosn, "");
        return JsonData;
    }
}
```

And then you can use these functions to save and get json data as below:

LocalSharedPrefrences.saveHomePageJosnData(Context,JsonDataToSave);

String getJsonData = LocalSharedPrefrences.getHomePageJosnData(Context)

Comment: JsonDataToSave       in wich parameter pass?

Comment: You need to pass the String jsonData which you want to save in shared prefrence in second position of saveHomePageJosnData function.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is structured and you want to access it in parts, you should better use `SQLite`.

If you just want to cache this data and you will use it completely in future better use `SharedPref` as you won't create schema for it hence SQLite will be a waste of resource and time both.

Comment: Check if data is there is sharedPref 
if(sharedPref.contains(KEY) )
   // Load data from sharedPref
else
  // make network call

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can save your json data and and you can use it in offline by using SharedPreferences in android.

First you need to java class i.e. pojo class using Json, Convert that json into above class object.

To save that json -->

```
private SharedPreferences preferences;
preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("your Key String", gson.toJson(here will be your json class object));
editor.commit();
```

To retrieve That Json-->

```
gson.fromJson(preferences.getString("your same Key String", null), your json class.class);
```

In this you will get object of that pojo class i.e. converted json class object.